# pyvis hierarchical layout not displaying correctly when many edges are added

Tags: python, networkx, pyvis

I am trying to produce a tripartite network using pyvis because it's interactive. When I add nodes and assign them levels, and then display [nodes only network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyz9Q.png), the output seems ok. When I add edges and then display [full network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VDpE.png), I just see a straight line. With few nodes and edges, it works, but not with all the nodes (about 300) and edges (about 700).

Here is the code for the example that does work. But if you look at the pictures and point out where could the problem be, it will be helpful.

```py
from pyvis.network import Network
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ddd = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
ccc = {'p', 'q', 'r'}
yyy = {'x', 'y', 'z'}
edge_list_tuples = [('a', 'q'), ('b', 'p'), ('b', 'q'), ('p', 'y'), ('r', 'y'), ('r', 'z'), ('x', 'x')]
g = nx.Graph()
pyvs = Network(notebook=True, height = "100%", width = "100%", layout=True)

g.add_nodes_from(yyy, bipartite="yy")
g.add_nodes_from(ccc, bipartite="cc")
g.add_nodes_from(ddd, bipartite="dd")
g.add_edges_from(edge_list_tuples)

color_map = nx.get_node_attributes(g, "bipartite")

for key in color_map:
    if color_map[key] == "dd":
        color_map[key] = "yellow"
        lvl = 3
    if color_map[key] == "cc":
        color_map[key] = "green"
        lvl = 2
    if color_map[key] == "yy":
        color_map[key] = "blue"
        lvl = 1
    pyvs.add_node(key, color=color_map[key], level=lvl)

pyvs.add_edges(g.edges()) # The nodes should exist. Unlike in networkx. 
pyvs.show_buttons(filter_=['physics'])
pyvs.show("output_network.html")
```

@jylls here is the code used with original data

```py
from pyvis.network import Network
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlrd

file = "./so-factors.xls"

ddd = set()
ccc = set()
yyy = set()
edge_list_tuples = [] # empty list which gets tuples of pairs (ddd, ccc) and (ccc, yyy)

book = xlrd.open_workbook(file)

sheet1 = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for row in range(sheet1.nrows-1):
    data = sheet1.row_slice(row+1)
    ddd.add(data[0].value)
    ccc.add(data[1].value)
    edge_list_tuples.append((data[0].value, data[1].value))

sheet2 = book.sheet_by_index(1)
for row in range(sheet2.nrows-1):
    data = sheet2.row_slice(row+1)
    ccc.add(data[0].value)
    yyy.add(data[1].value)
    edge_list_tuples.append((data[0].value, data[1].value))

g = nx.Graph()
pyvs = Network(notebook=True, height = "100%", width = "100%", layout=True)

g.add_nodes_from(yyy, bipartite="yy")
g.add_nodes_from(ccc, bipartite="cc")
g.add_nodes_from(ddd, bipartite="dd")
g.add_edges_from(edge_list_tuples)

color_map = nx.get_node_attributes(g, "bipartite")

for key in color_map:
    if color_map[key] == "dd":
        color_map[key] = "yellow"
        lvl = 3
    if color_map[key] == "cc":
        color_map[key] = "green"
        lvl = 2
    if color_map[key] == "yy":
        color_map[key] = "blue"
        lvl = 1
    pyvs.add_node(key, color=color_map[key], level=lvl)

pyvs.add_edges(g.edges()) # Without this line, the first picture in original question and with this causes second picture in the question. 
pyvs.show_buttons(filter_=['physics'])
pyvs.show("./output-gitignore/my_output_network.html")
```

Comment: Could you also provide the code for the example that doesn't work?

Comment: @jylls I've added the code. It is reading from an excel file with two sheets one capturing the relationship between level 2 and level 3 factors while second captures relationships between level 2 and level 1. Hopefully it's more clear.